# Problema ao salvar

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Somente um formulário que está me retornando esse erro, a questão que eu não sei oque pode ser ou como faz para arrumar, alguns pedem pra coloca o relacionamento em cascata oque já está.

> NHibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: BlogWeb.Models.Veiculo, Entity: BlogWeb.Models.Veiculo

Linha de retorno de erro:

```
public void Adiciona(Abastecimento abastecimento)
    {
        ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        session.Save(abastecimento);
        tx.Commit();
    }
```

Veiculo Mapping:

```
public class VeiculoMapping : ClassMap<Veiculo>
{
    public VeiculoMapping()
    {
    Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(p => p.NCarro);
    Map(p => p.Modelo);
    Map(p => p.Ano);

    }
}
```

Veiculo Model:

```
public class Veiculo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int NCarro { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Modelo { get; set; }
    public virtual int Ano { get; set; }
}
```

Abastecimento Mapping:

```
public class AbastecimentoMapping : ClassMap <Abastecimento>
    {
        public AbastecimentoMapping()
        {
            Id(a => a.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(a => a.DtAbastecido);
            Map(a => a.Litro);
            Map(a => a.VlrUnit);
            Map(a => a.Km);
            Map(a => a.TotalGasto);
            Map(a => a.Km_Andado);
            References(a => a.NomeProduto, "NomeProdutoId");
            References(a => a.Autor, "AutorId");
            References(a => a.NumCarro, "NumCarroId");
        }
    }
```

Abastecimento Model:

```
public class Abastecimento
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual int Litro { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DtAbastecido { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal VlrUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalGasto { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km_Andado { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual Compra NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public virtual Veiculo NumCarro { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Se tu formatou o PC, você trouxe o banco de dados além do projeto?

Comment: Sim, trouxe tudo inclusive o banco de dados, tenho três backups do banco que fica no servidores, no storage e no proprio computador

Comment: @EmanuelF O restante dos formulario, salva tranquilamente, somente essa que da problema

Comment: Abastecimento está referenciado o Veículo?

Comment: @EmanuelF Abastecimento pega Id do Veiculo que fica na tabela veiculo

Comment: Só pra descargo de consciência. Esse veículo já está salvo no sistema?

Comment: @EmanuelF Descobri o erro, por causa de um erro de ortografia, quando coloquei para chamar a classe do Veiculo, a variavel é Id e eu tinha colocado pra chamar por id e não Id

Comment: Estava procurando por alguma coisa que não existia, e retornando o erro. Se resolveu, perfeito!

Comment: @EmanuelF Não sabe o ódio que to, fiquei 3 dias com esse problema e descubro que algo idiota, mas obrigado pela atenção e paciência

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está salvando uma entidade, que possui relacionamento com alguma entidade que foi alterada mas que não foi salva antes.

Se for este caso, você tem duas opções:

- Salva a outra entidade antes de salvar esta;
- Mapear o relacionamento como `cascade`, afim de que nessa situação a outra entidade relacionada seja salva também.

**Falando em cascade**

Para cada operação básica da sessão NHibernate - incluindo `Persist (), Merge (), SaveOrUpdate (), Delete (), Lock (), Refresh (), Evict (), Replicate ()` - existe um estilo de cascata correspondente. Respectivamente, os estilos em cascata são chamados persistir, mesclar, salvar-atualização, excluir, bloquear, atualizar, expulsar, replicar. O estilo em cascata para `Save ()` e `Update ()` é save-update; para `SaveAndUpdateCopy ()` é mesclar; e para `PersistOnFlush ()` é persistente. E remover é um alias para deletar.

Se você deseja que uma operação seja conectada em cascata ao longo de uma associação, você deve indicar isso no documento de mapeamento. Por exemplo:

```
<one-to-one name="person" cascade="persist"/>
```

Estilos em cascata meus combinados:

```
<one-to-one name="person" cascade="persist,delete,lock"/>
```

Você pode usar `cascade = "all"` para especificar que todas as operações devem ser conectadas em cascata ao longo da associação. A cascata `padrão = "none"` especifica que nenhuma operação deve ser conectada em cascata.

Recomendo ler mais nesse post em Inglês [AQUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058417/nhibernate-definitive-cascade-application-guide)

Comment: Emanuel obrigado pela explicação, mas onde eu colocaria cascade em uma mapping do nhibernate `public class VeiculoMapping : ClassMap<Veiculo>
    {
        public VeiculoMapping()
        {
        Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(p => p.NCarro);
        Map(p => p.Modelo);
        Map(p => p.Ano);
        Map(p => p.Km);
        
        }
    }`

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam você tem um Vaiculo.hbm.xml ?

Comment: Não tenho, mas tenho a RouteConfig.cs, não sei se é algo que tenha que altera, o problema que outros formulários, que fazem o CRUD perfeitamente, somente esse que não da certo, porém é a classe mais importante

Comment: Como disse na resposta. Esta tentando salvar a Entidade Abastecimento, mas fez alguma alteração na entidade Veículo que não foi salva.

Comment: Estranho, isso que to tentando achar, porque se fosse no banco ele iria adiciona uma coluna pelo mapping, está tudo certo, tanto no model, mapping e viewmodel veiculo esse é o problema, porque ele me retorno o erro na model veiculo

Comment: Edita a resposta e adiciona o mapeamento das duas entidades.

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta tanto o mapping de abastecimento onde tento salva e retorna o erro e o mapping e model de onde ele fala o erro que é o Veiculo Model